# Can listview.setOnItemClickListener pass to its intent the SQLite _id instead of position?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-intent, android-listview

I have an activity that lists all rows of a SQLite table. Initially, as I populate the table, clicking on items will open up each item as expected. However, the database is supposed to be modified and if I delete some rows, the list gets out of sequence (the items' SQLite *_id* and position in the list are mismatched). Is there a way to retrieve the item's *_id* from the SQLite table and pass that through the intent?

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FilmEditActivity.class);
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(id));
            i.putExtra(FilmEditActivity.EXTRA_FILM_ID, position+1); //sql starts at 1; java at 0
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "position:" + String.valueOf(position) + "; id:" + String.valueOf(id),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you keep a reference to your adapter, you can call `getItemId(position)` on it. For the existing CursorAdapter implementations, this should give you the `_id` -- of course, if you wrote your own adapter, you should make sure yours does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you work with a CursorAdapter which is certainly the best way to populate a list from an SQLite database.

To retrieve the primary key of a clicked entry you can do the following:

```
int adapterPosition = position - listView.getHeaderViewsCount();
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) yourAdapter.getItem(adapterPosition);
int id = cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex("_id") );
```

Pass this id to your activity and you should be all set.

The parameter id passed into the onItemClick is what the adapter returns in a getItemId(int) calls which should be the same as the _id in your database. The documentation states:

> Get the row id associated with the specified position in the list.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemId(int)

Row id isn't explicitly the primary key but it's probably safe to assume that they are identical (checking the CursorAdapter.getItemId(int) code confirms that assumption).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `CursorAdapter` then the param `id` passed to the `onItemClick()` is exactly the SQLite "_id".

There is also another way to get "_id"

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use The id parameter instead of the position parameter, the inbuilt class already helps in getting the id from the source data. after implementing the

```
onItemCliclListener
```

in the onItemClick function, use the id paramenter as show in the code below

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // this will be executed in respective of id
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ViewLyrics.class);
        Bundle sendid = new Bundle();

        sendid.putLong(database.KEY_ROWID, id);
         i.putExtras(sendid);
         startActivity(i);          
    }
```